# Weird regex match behavior. Is my regex wrong? Or is it a compiler error?

Tags: regex, c++11, boost, cygwin

I am doing some work using regex in C++, tried both the std::regex and boost:regex (1.58.0).

And I am getting this weird matches. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, const char* argc[])
{
    regex log_line_regex_(".+\\s(.+)$");
    char* log_line = "06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState";
    smatch matches; 
    if (regex_match(std::string(log_line), matches, log_line_regex_))
    {
        std::cout << "match: " << log_line << std::endl;
        unsigned i;
        for (i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "$" << i << ": " << std::string(matches[i].first, matches[i].second) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
match: 06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState
$0: 06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeSt`
$1: ModeSt`
```

See? The output is mangled :(
As I said I tried with `boost 1.58.0` and `g++ (GCC) 4.9.2` both on Cygwin

[Compiled at Ideone also fails](http://ideone.com/S8q5oV)

I find it weird that boost::regex fails at this simple regex. So is my usage wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quality of implementation thing.

Two issues are at play:

- the majority of std library implementation don't implement `std::regex` well, completely or at all. This is a frequent source of confusion. IIRC GCC only supports it from 5.x up.
- The other issue is that you input (`std::string(log_line)`) is a temporary (!). `smatch` will contain and return iterators into a temporary whose lifetime ended at the end of the `regex_match` call¹.

Fixing it at least makes this work on GCC 5.x:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c72b4175d7b2efef)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex log_line_regex_(".+?\\s(.+)");

    char const *log_line = "06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState";

    std::smatch matches;

    std::string input(log_line);
    if (regex_match(input, matches, log_line_regex_))
    {
        std::cout << "match: " << log_line << std::endl;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << "$" << i << ": " << std::string(matches[i].first, matches[i].second) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
match: 06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState
$0: 06-29 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState
$1: 18:20:08.938 1031 1099 D WifiStateMachine: processMsgConnect oo ModeState
```

---

¹ actually the containing *full-expression*

Comment: In case you like, here's a [live stream of me answering your question](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/the-stdregex-ub-case-and-a-circular_buffer/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Wow, thanks! This really fixes it hahaha.
I am a noob at C++, just learning, totally forgot that temporary.

Comment: @Henrique I didn't joke when I said it's a QOI issue; GCC 5.1 doesn't even _accept_ the rvalue-ref version of the invocation (it's explicitly deleted). I'm not sure whether this is actually due to a standards defect report (DR) or just a nice gesture from the GNU libstdc++ implementors.

Comment: `GCC only supports it from 5.x up` It's actually supported from 4.9, but the first few versions have some bugs. They are all probably fixed in 5.x

Comment: @nhahtdh The way I remember "have some bugs" meant that 80% of regex just didn't work (it did compile though). On my 4.8.2 and 4.9 install it didn't work.

Comment: @sehe: 4.8.x will simply not work. I think simple regex works in 4.9 (as demonstrated in several posts on SO), but I don't know what is the extent, so I'd take your word for it.